# Add class to li if content is a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would it be possible to add a certain class to a li that contains a certain string of text using JavaScript/[jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)?

UPDATE/NEW QUESTION:
Instead of detecting the content of the li, can I have it add the class if the li has another specified class?

Comment: Sure -- so what's your question?

Comment: @DavidHoerster How to do it! :P

Comment: `$('li:contains(mytext)').addClass('myclass')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the fellow's extended question:

```
$('li.yourClass').addClass('anotherClass');
```

You're asking really basic questions. I'd recommend you just spend some time with the beginner jQuery tutorials on the site and you'll understand all of this stuff much better.

Edit: IGNORE MY OLD ANSWER. You learn something every day. Do this, not what I said:

```
//http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
$('li:contains('+ searchText +')').addClass('myClass');
```

Old answer:

```
$('li').each(function(){

    var _this = $(this);
    if( _this.text() === testString ){
        _this.addClass('myClass');
    }

});
```

In the if statement, you can change that to check the .html() of your li or even do a more advanced regex if you need that. But basically, you have to loop through the li's in one form or another to check their content against your testString.

Comment: Could make this better by not calling `$(this)` twice

Comment: this is good, except it only works if its an exact match.  You might want to use the match()

Comment: How would I do it if there are multiple words? Would I use + to separate them?

Comment: @KennethGarza The question title makes it sound like an exact match is required

Comment: Love it.  I didnt know that existed either.  You do learn something every day.

Comment: @KennethGarza I want it to match a full string, not just part of one

Comment: I updated my question with some more stuff. Sorry for being a help hog! :(

Comment: After implementing the updated solution, it's not working. You can see what I did wrong at http://newbowmanvillezoo.com

Comment: Sorry Ian, but pointing us to your zoo site doesn't indicate what you've done or whats wrong. If you want anyone to look, indicate what you did on your site and what you are/are not expecting to happen.

Comment: A quick look at your source-code shows you've added the code you gleaned from this question right at the top of your page, before jQuery has been loaded. The code needs to be run after jQuery has been included on the page and preferably when the document is ready. These are really, really basic missteps. Please spend some time on http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ and http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('certain string') !== -1;
}).addClass('certainClass');
```

You can use the jQuery [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function.

The filter function can be passed a selector instead of a function:

```
$('li').filter('.specified-class').addClass('certainClass');
```

at which point you should probably just update the initial selector:

```
$('li.specified-class').addClass('certainClass');
```

Comment: I updated my question with some more stuff. Sorry for being a help hog! :(